# Is a .apk the only type of file that is executable on Android (not rooted)?

Tags: android, apk, executable

To be more precise, is a .apk the only file that could potentially have malicious behavior?

Comment: Android is basically a Linux system. So you can have native executables, shell scripts, Java programs, ... They are probably not easy to install but are executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that *any* file can be malicious, regardless of file extension. What is more important is the contents, and what is opening/parsing the file in question. For example, someone could send you a malicious `.mp3`, which infects your system by exploiting a vulnerability in the music player that loads it.

While any file *can* be malicious, I would say `.apk`'s have the most *potential* to be malicious. The interesting part is that the Android team probably has invested some serious effort into protecting the loading of `.apk`s and so it is probably unlikely that just opening a `.apk` will do harm. Only if you allow the program to install with any invasive permissions will you be open to attack.